# How to append many objects without appending materials

Tags: materials, append

Is there any option, to append many objects without appending their materials?

Example: I have `scene1.blend` with `cube` object and `wood` material. 
I append `cube` with `wood` to `scene2.blend`, where there also is `cube` and `wood` material.

Blender logically creates `cube.001` and `wood.001`, but I don't want `wood.001`, I need Blender to use the existing `wood` material instead of creating a new copy.

I'm talking about thousands of objects and hundreds materials. For example now I have `natural wood.##` ... `natural wood.017` and all are exactly the same, and I have few dozens of materials like this multiplied by 17 object copies.

My English is not very good and this is problem little bit hard to explain, so I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: We can understand your problem alright, but unfortunately I don't think there is any way to do this currently in Blender. I'll investigate but I have never seen a workaround.

Comment: This is a great question!  I definitely think there should be an option to append without materials.  A good idea to pitch to the devs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After importing the objects you can use a python script to remove the use of duplicate materials. As each duplicate gets a numeric extension we can test whether the material without the extension exists and use it if it does exist.

```
import bpy

mat_list = bpy.data.materials

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    for s in o.material_slots:
        if s.material.name[-3:].isnumeric():
            # the last 3 characters are numbers
            if s.material.name[:-4] in mat_list:
                # there is a material without the numeric extension so use it
                s.material = mat_list[s.material.name[:-4]]
```

Comment: WOW,  Exactly what I need. This script perfectly clean up my materials. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as correct if solved your problem, or at least up-voting it if it helped you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a solution to the append problem directly, more of a cleanup technique, but if you only have one material per object you can easily select all objects with the same base material name (say `wood.001` `wood.002` `wood.003`) by searching for `wood` in the outliner.

Just go to the *Outliner* and search for your material name, after searching press <kbd>A</kbd> over the list of search results to pre-select all displayed objects in that list, then <kbd>Righ-Click</kbd> over them and choose *Select*.

That should take care of selecting all of them in the 3D view. Now in the 3D view and without deselecting the previously selected objects Shift-Select the object with the original `wood` you want to use to make it the *Active Object*.

Alternatively you may instead change the material manually to the desired original `wood` on any of the search results by making it the *Active Object* first. (Just Shift-Select one of the already selected to make it active)

Afterwards you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *Link > Materials* to make them all use the same `wood` material instead.

(Bottom line here is *Link > Materials* works from the active object to the selection)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, this work, but not very useful in my case. The problem is "Shift-Select" must be done manually. Or is there way how to select all marked object at once?

Comment: Yes, you can easily select them all at once, I updated my answer, check for details above.

Comment: I need explore Outliner features deeper :D Thank you for advice. This really helped me and it also useful for future in many cases :-)