# How to copy objects in Blender without copying their materials?

Tags: materials, objects

Need to copy objects from one layer to another in the same scene, but sometimes also one scene to another.

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for this a lot, but problem is now there are 5 copies of around 20 materials.

EG:  Material1, Material1.001, Material1.002, Material1.003, Material1.004, etc

Another [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/3ebk11/newbie_question_is_there_any_way_to_stop_the/) said to duplicate the objects instead, then move them to another layer.  But couldn't see how to do that for scenes, and prefer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>. Is there a setting or way to stop copying the materials but still copy objects using that method.

Don't want to link the objects either.  Want unique, standalone copies of the objects.  But only one instance of each material.

Comment: See this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57960/how-to-append-many-objects-without-appending-materials/57984#57984

Comment: As far as I know there is no native direct way of doing this through the UI alone, only through scripting

Comment: Don't know the first thing about scripting so not workable for me, at this stage.  Your link above explains how to at least clean up the problem, if no one else knows how to prevent the problem w/o scripting.  Thanks.

Comment: You can create linked duplicates instead of full ones of object (`Alt`+`D`); then make linked dupe use different object and mesh datablock. Same with moving them between scenes. No way to do what you want using exactly `Ctrl`+`C` / `Ctrl`+`V`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Material Duplication](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55233/disable-material-duplication)

Comment: Sorry @MrZak not sure how to make the duplicate use different object and/or mesh datablock.  Can you please explain?

Comment: As a confused beginner. I thought it was copying edits to the object, but that was because I was editing the material that it shared with the other object. 

I realized this and created a new material. Hope this helps another newbie on this same track.

Answer (score 3):

To copy objects without copying materials create [linked duplicate](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/duplication.html#linked-duplicates) of all adjacent objects; they will use the same material (along with other data). Then in order to make linked objects independent from each other (sharing only material), [make them single-user](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user) via *Object > Make Single User* menu (or press <kbd>U</kbd> while in 3D Viewport) and choose *Object & Data*.

You can do the same [between different scenes by linking them to that scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/how-move-object-between-scenes); press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and in *Objects To Scene* dropdown choose scene to link them to.
Make sure to make them single-user after linking if you want them as independent objects.

Comment: The linked duplicate url is broken in your answer, here's a working one https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/duplication.html?highlight=linked%20duplicate#linked-duplicates

Comment: new link: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html