# How to merge different material with same base color?

Tags: texturing, scripting, shaders

I imported an FBX file generated from Naviswork. In this scene I have a lot of different materials with the same base color.

Is there's a way to join all the material with same color?

[image]

Comment: Resolved by adding a script for rename with rgb values the materials before this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154371/blender-2-8-how-to-select-multiple-object-with-the-same-diffuse-color-in-princi