# remove unassigned materials from an object... how do I do this?

Tags: materials

I'm currently using Blender 2.8 and the function to remove unassigned materials from a mesh doesn't seem to be available anywhere. In 2.79 there were 2 addon's that dealt with this, "Material Utils Specials" and "Amaranth". They both had options for cleaning out material slots on an object. What is the workflow in 2.8 for doing this?

Comment: Doesn't the minus button next to the materials slots work for you?

Comment: that - button will remove a material slot yes. It will delete a material even if it is assigned to faces though. The tools I had before remove all materials that are not assigned to any faces.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129082/delete-all-materials-that-arent-assigned-to-a-face

Answer (score 0):

If a material is not assigned then it could be in the orphan data, just purge your orphan data and that should do the trick

Comment: Like i've already commented, that's not the case. You can have materials assigned to objects, that are assigned to zero faces, and Blender does not see these as orphaned data. There's no way to 'clean' the mesh of these materials other than manually go through and see if they are assigned to faces by clicking the 'select' button on each one.

Comment: @RobBeddall Well I found this. Might be what you are looking for: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/J8cbbc/

Comment: Yes this is the exact problem I am facing. It seems that there is no fix for this in the 2.8 release candidates, although an updated version of the Amaranth add on, which has a tool for this, was added to one of the daily builds, it isn't in the official release candidates.